# How do I do to recover the entire folder structure from an erased hard drive using totally free software?

Tags: data-recovery, file-recovery

I was using my 2TB SSD, and after a while, maybe because of a mis-click, it got entirely hard erased, only few files survived (40KB).

After that, I attempted to use Glary Undelete to recover files, but I realized that it doesn't recover folder structures.

I have many files from many folders and Lightroom catalogs that won't work anymore if the folder structure isn't the same as before.

How do I do to recover the entire folder structure from an erased hard drive using totally free software?

Comment: Tried testdisk? Of course a backup is easiest

Comment: @Xen2050 not yet, but will give it a try

Comment: The topic is still active imho. Can someone suggest a good free/paid program to recover lost files and folder structure ?

Answer (score -2):

After digging more into Recuva, I found a "Recover file structure" option.

No EaseUS tool needed.

Comment: This situation sounds bad, but honestly the problem with this answer is perhaps the problem with the question. You are basically just asking for a free piece of software. And the answer? Can’t find one so just buy it.

Comment: @JakeGould I said I found one. Recuva has the option I was looking for, it works and it solved my problem.